# How to marshal a COM-Parameter as VT_ARRAY of VT_RECORD

Tags: c#, com, marshalling, com-interop

I've already done some extensive search, but I can't seem to find anything matching my problem.

The task I'm currently working on is to create a WCF-Wrapper for some DCOM-Objects. This already works great for the most parts, but now I'm stuck with one invocation that expects a `VT_ARRAY` containing `VT_RECORD`-Objects.

Marshalling as `VT_ARRAY` is not a problem, but how can I tell COM that the elements in this array are `VT_RECORD`s?

This is the invocation as I current use it.

```
InitTestCase(testCaseName, parameterFileName, testCase, cellInfos.ToArray());
```

The parameter I'm talking about is the last one. It's defined as `List<CellInfo>`, `CellInfo` itself is already attributed with `Guid("7D422961-331E-47E2-BC71-7839E9E77D39")` and `ComVisible(true)`. It's *not* a struct but a class.

This is the condition failing on the native side: `if (VT_RECORD == varCellConfig.vt)...`

Because of old software using these interfaces, changing the native side is not an option

Any idea?

Comment: You get VT_RECORD from storing a struct in an array element of type object.  In other words, a boxed struct.  The [Guid] of the struct must match the one declared in the type library.

Comment: Ok, I will try this as soon as possible and give a feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I've tried it and it doesn't seem to work. I've checked the layout of the class, changed it to a struct, validated the GUID, boxed all entries, everything to no avail. The called method WORKS with another class imported from COM. But I'd rather have my own objects than COM-Objects sent through WCF...